# How to send an argument to another file in python 3

Tags: python

So, I have been looking at other threads on this topic but they do not use the Module version of passing the argument to the other file, if so wasn't explained clearly enough for me to understand.

I have tried just to show I'm not just asking:

```
#MoneyCounter.py
import Password

enter = False
Password.system(enter)

def start(check):
    if check == True:
        main()
    elif check == False:
        print("Critical Error occured")
        exit()
```

And my other file

```
#Password.py
import MoneyCounter

def system(check):
    if check == False:
        password() #This goes to password def not mentioned in this code
    elif check == True:
         MoneyCounter.start(check)
```

The error I am getting is the Module Password has no attribute system

Comment: What do you mean by “passing an argument to a file”? Also, your issue here is you cannot import module A from module B if module A also imports module B (aka. import loop)

Comment: You named the argument `check` but use `enter` in the function..

Comment: Well, you *can* do a circular import, but you need to know what you're doing.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `exit` should only be used in interactive python (because of side-effects involving `stdin`).  You should use `sys.exit()` instead.

Comment: thanks cdark. But how would i be able to do the circular import which is what i would like to do since i want to send arguments back and forth between the files

Answer (score 2):

> The error I am getting is the Module Password has no attribute system

Of course it doesn't. The definition doesn't exist by the time the line of code is executed, since execution of the first file got interrupted by the import.

Either refactor or reorder your code so that the name isn't accessed until it exists, or remove the requirement that each module has for the other.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I would put more emphasis on the refactoring option. Having circular imports is just asking for trouble and odd errors (like this).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is circular dependency/imports.

An `import` statement really *executes* the code in the imported file; that is, all the statements are executed, everything that is `def`ed in the imported file gets defined etc. `imports` get imported, too.

So what's happening is this:

1. you run

`$ python MoneyCounter.py`

2. Python reads MoneyCounter.py, executes its first statement: `import Password`
3. Python reads Password.py, and executes its first statement: `import MoneyCounter.py`
4. Python reads MoneyCounter.py, this time it encounters `import Password`, but already has password in its list of known names; so it continues to

`enter=False; Password.system(enter)`.

5. Now, Python already has a `Password` in its name lookup dictionary: the half-imported `Password`. In that, `def system…` hasn't happened yet, so `Password.system` is still unknown.

Generally, your architecture is *questionable*. Why would the `Password` "utility" module call into your "master" business logic? Better not do that, but write code that actually checks the return value of `Password.system` and acts based on that in your `MoneyCounter.py`.

Comment: Step 4 is wrong given step 1, since the main script is always `__main__` regardless of what filename it has.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I must admit I'm confused: There's no usage of `__main__` anywhere?

Comment: Right, which means that `Password` would be importing a *second* copy of MoneyCounter.py as `MoneyCounter` in addition to the copy as `__main__`. Trap for young players.

Comment: aaaah yes indeed, and the point is that upon importing that, Python would encounter `import Password`; now, already having a name `Password` in its dict, it doesn't `import Password`?

Comment: Correct, it would use the reference it already has. Which doesn't yet have the attribute in question.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that `MoneyCounter.py` is the entry point (the name you run from the command-line), then I suggest you replace this:

```
enter = False
Password.system(enter)
```

with this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    enter = False
    Password.system(enter)
```

That will only be executed from the entry-point (which is called `__main__`) and not when it is imported.  However, you should reconsider your design.

Edit:

`name` is a reference to the text name of the current module.  With modules that are explicitly imported the name is taken from the filename, but the entry-point (where the program starts) is always called `__main__`.  So we can always test if we are running as an imported module or as an entry-point.

This test is *extremely* common in python.  This way we can provide additional functionality depending on whether we run a module as a program or `import` it.

Comment: can you please explain what
    __name__
and "__main__" mean? With the underscores